# translation along a curve on two common surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking for a proof of the following:

If two surfaces S1 and S2 are tangent along the curve C, then parallel translation along C on the surface S1 is also a parallel translation along C on the surface S2.
That is two arbitrary surfaces (S1 and S2) touch each other along a curve (C). For example a cone is placed on a sphere. They touch/contact each other along a circle $C$.

Comment: Two arbitrary surfaces (S1 and S2) are touching with other in a curve (C). Just for example a cone is placed  on a sphere. They touch each other in a circle.

Comment: Please check how geodesic curvature changes. ( second fundamental form of surface theory.)

Answer (score 0):

A vector field on $S_i$ is parallel along $C$ if its covariant derivative along $C$ is $0$. But this is the projection of its usual derivative (as a mapping to $\Bbb R^3$) along $C$ to the tangent plane of $S_i$. Since the tangent planes agree, these projections agree, and so one is $0$ if and only if the other is $0$.